# AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_name'

Tags: python-2.7, appium, pageobjects, appium-ios, python-behave

I am new to testing with Appium and I'm running my tests with Behave using a page object model structure and ran into an issue that I am completely unable to resolve.

when trying to run my behave script I am met with the following error:

```
$ behave --tags=@test1 features/login_page.feature 
Feature: Login Page # features/login_page.feature:1

  @test1
  Scenario: This will test that given a filled SUBJECT_ID_FIELD and PARTICIPATION_CODE field the LOGIN_BUTTON will be enabled.  # features/login_page.feature:5
    Given I navigate to the log in screen                                                                                       # features/steps/login_page.py:4 0.353s
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/behave/model.py", line 1329, in run
          match.run(runner.context)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/behave/matchers.py", line 98, in run
          self.func(context, *args, **kwargs)
        File "features/steps/login_page.py", line 6, in step_impl
          login_page = pages.Login(context)
        File "/Users/admin/Documents/iris-ios/features/pages/login.py", line 9, in __init__
          self.subject_id_field = self.driver.find_element_by_name(self.ELEMENT_NAME_SUBJECT_ID_FIELD)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 321, in __getattr__
          raise AttributeError(msg)
      AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_name'

    When I enter valid details into the username field                                                                          # None
    And I enter valid details into the password field                                                                           # None
    Then I will verify the LOGIN_BUTTON is enabled                                                                              # None


Failing scenarios:
  features/login_page.feature:5  This will test that given a filled SUBJECT_ID_FIELD and PARTICIPATION_CODE field the LOGIN_BUTTON will be enabled.

0 features passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped
0 scenarios passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped
0 steps passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped, 3 undefined
Took 0m0.353s
```

My environment.py file looks like this:

```
from appium import webdriver
import desired_capabilities


def before_scenario(context, scenario):
    desired_caps = desired_capabilities.get_desired_capabilities()
    context.driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub", desired_caps)
```

and my steps file looks like this:

```
import pages


@given(u'I navigate to the log in screen')
def step_impl(context):
    login_page = pages.Login(context.driver)
    login_page.enter_subject_id("HELLO WORLD")
```

And finally my pages file for my page object model looks like:

```
class Login():
    ELEMENT_NAME_SUBJECT_ID_FIELD = "Subject_ID_field"
    ELEMENT_NAME_PARTICIPATION_CODE_FIELD =  "participation_code_field"
    ELEMENT_NAME_LOGIN_BUTTON = "login_button"

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        self.subject_id_field = self.driver.find_element_by_name(self.ELEMENT_NAME_SUBJECT_ID_FIELD)

    def enter_subject_id(self,text_to_enter):
        self.subject_id_field.send_keys(text_to_enter)
```

any help resolving this would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you ensured that `webdriver.Remote(...)` is indeed returning a WebDriver Remote object? I would check that URL address that you're specifying--it looks like it came straight from the [docs](https://github.com/appium/python-client).

Answer (score 1):

The AttributeError points out that the method `self.driver.find_element_by_name(...)` doesn't exist because `self.driver` is a `Context` object.  The code you pasted looks fine but there must be somewhere it's setting behave's `Context` object instead of the actual `context.driver` as returned from `webdriver.Remote(...)`.

To debug this I would recommend implementing something like behave's [BEHAVE_DEBUG_ON_ERROR](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#debug-on-error-in-case-of-step-failures) flag to break into `ipdb` on failure, and then `assert False` in various location to peek at the value of `context.driver` to see where it's turning into a `Context` object.